# Regressão Linear SAS

Tags: matemática, procedure

Estou trabalhando em um projeto em que desenvolvo indicadores de alteração de tendência. Um deles envolve regressão linear olhando 12 meses, ou seja, entro com 12 pontos  consecutivo de uma série temporal e quero a previsão do um décimo terceiro. Atrás de algumas pesquisas verifiquei que o procedimento "proc reg" devolve o ponto que necessito. No entanto tenho que fazer esse procedimento milhares de vezes, pois somente consigo o ponto se fizer uma tabela com 13 linhas. Alguém conhece uma solução, ou alguma função que eu possa usar e substituir a chamada do proc reg?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

"Reg proc" você deve estar falando de regression procedures se você olhar a fundo vai notar que existe diferentes classes.
O caminho mais simples que vejo é aplicar regressão linear simplesmente olhando valores do passado para predizer o futuro ou seja o caminho que você tomou ainda me parece ser a melhor opção, eu ainda consigo imaginar o uso de uma interpolação linear que é amplamente utilizado quando se deseja encontrar valores desconhecidos entre dois pontos e claro pode ser usado como análise para prever qualquer ponto a partir de valores anteriores, um exemplo prático pode ser encontrado neste site http://www.johndcook.com/interpolator.htm por exemplo entre com uma sequência e deixe o último valor vazio e veja o resultado, como dito anteriormente é possivel prever valores em qualquer posição.